# How do you repair a 'Suspect' SQL Server 2008 database

Tags: sql-server

My database has gone offline, it is highlighted as 'Suspect'.

Foolishly, I haven't got a recent backup.

Is there a way of quickly restoring the database?

Comment: rule number one, don't drop it and try to bring it back up. Please read: http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/creating-detaching-re-attaching-and-fixing-a-suspect-database/  basically set it to emergency -> single user -> try repair with data loss.... there is never a guarantee that it will work. The next thing to do is to create a maintenance plan ;)

Comment: See this answer:  http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/2175/10832

Comment: @RayofCommand FYI repair with data loss is always the last resort.  There are any number of ways you can fix your database without risking losing data.